# multiple level of excel columns for nested dictionary with Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a nested dictionary and would like to convert it to an excel file with multiple levels of columns.
Here is the dictionary

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62f0eb4b2a5d08235eefdd9a"
  },
  "native": [
    {
      "collecttime": "08-Aug-2022 20:54:03",
      "hostname": "R3",
      "version": "16.9",
      "ios_users": [
        {
          "cisco": 15
        },
        {
          "developer": 15
        },
        {
          "root": 15
        }
      ],
      "domain_name": "cisco.com"
    }
  ],
  "interface": [
    {
      "name": "GigabitEthernet1",
      "enabled": true,
      "ietf-ip:ipv4": {
        "address": [
          {
            "ip": "10.10.20.48",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ietf-ip:ipv6": {}
    },
     {"name": "GigabitEthernet3",
      "type": "iana-if-type:ethernetCsmacd",
      "enabled": true,
      "ietf-ip:ipv4": {
        "address": [
          {
            "ip": "172.18.1.1",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.252"
          },
          {
            "ip": "192.168.200.6",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ietf-ip:ipv6": {}
    }
    ]
}
```

I would like to convert it like the attached format[image]

I could not figure out how to let Pandas write column names itself on different rows. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You may create 3 dataframes and combine them as 1 dataframe then output to excel

Answer (score 0):

With the dictionnary (I call it `data`) you provided, here is how to do it with three intermediate dataframes, as suggested in the comments:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data["_id"], index=range(0, len(data["_id"])))
df1.columns = [""]

df2 = (
    pd.DataFrame(data["native"][0])
    .drop(columns=["collecttime", "version", "domain_name"])
    .groupby("hostname")
    .agg(lambda x: x)
    .reset_index()
)
df2 = pd.concat(
    [df2["hostname"], pd.DataFrame(df2["ios_users"].tolist(), index=df2.index)], axis=1
)
df2.columns = ["hostname"] + [
    f"ios_users{col}" for col in df2.columns if col != "hostname"
]


df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["interface"]).drop(
    columns=["enabled", "ietf-ip:ipv6", "type"]
)
df3["ietf-ip:ipv4"] = df3["ietf-ip:ipv4"].apply(lambda x: x["address"])
df3 = df3.explode("ietf-ip:ipv4").reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = pd.concat([df3["name"], pd.json_normalize(df3["ietf-ip:ipv4"])], axis=1)
df3 = df3.groupby("name").agg(lambda x: x)
df3 = pd.concat(
    [df3["ip"].apply(pd.Series), df3["netmask"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1
).reset_index()
df3.columns = ["name", "ip0", "ip1", "netmask0", "netmask1"]
df3 = df3[["name", "ip0", "netmask0", "ip1", "netmask1"]]
```

```py
# Final dataframe
df = pd.concat(
    [df1, df2, df3], axis=1, keys=["_id.$oid", "native", "interface"]
).fillna("")

df.to_excel("temp.xlsx")
```

Output:

[image]